# Optimize multiple or Statements for a Set<String>

Tags: java

What will be the best way to optimize below code?

```
  protected void saveUserRoles(Set<String> userRoles) {
        if (userRoles != null && (userRoles.contains(StaticValues.LUMEN_SELECT_USER_ROLE)
                || userRoles.contains(StaticValues.EASY_SENSE_USER_ROLE)
                || userRoles.contains(StaticValues.TLED_USER_ROLE)||userRoles.contains(StaticValues.IR_APP_USER_ROLE))) {
            preferences.setUserRoles(userRoles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why does it need optimizing?

Comment: The code following && could be put in a switch that falls through

Comment: User Roles can grow...it will increase number of || statements.Thats why looking for optimization

Comment: @Nargis: Do you mean you're trying to keep the code readable, or are you concerned about performance? Those are very different concerns. How many roles are you expecting to need to test, and what do your performance benchmarks show in terms of how significant this is?

Comment: Put the static values in a set too and use set intersection.

Comment: @Jon I am looking at both readability and performance.At present there are 4 User Roles, it can grow up to 8

Comment: you can add left operator inside if statement and all others as a Switch statement inside above if. if(userRoles != null){ switch {} }.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just keep a list or array of the values to test against:

```
private static final List USER_ROLES_TO_SAVE = Arrays.asList(
     StaticValues.LUMEN_SELECT_USER_ROLE,
     StaticValues.EASY_SENSE_USER_ROLE,
     StaticValues.TLED_USER_ROLE,
     StaticValues.IR_APP_USER_ROLE);

protected void saveUserRoles(Set<String> userRoles) {
    if (userRoles == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (String candidate : USER_ROLES_TO_SAVE) {
         if (userRoles.contains(candidate)) {
             preferences.setUserRoles(userRoles);
             return;
         }
    }
}
```

That's now very easy to maintain and read - and as for performance, if you're only looking at expanding the list to about 8 entries, there's no point in trying to get fancy - I would be absolutely *astonished* if this became the bottleneck, and finding anything faster in terms of complexity than O(N) is unlikely to be useful given how small N is in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the logic to a method with a loop and variable arguments ([varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)), something like

```
private static boolean containsAny(Set<String> userRoles, String... roles) {
    if (userRoles == null || userRoles.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String role : roles) {
        if (userRoles.contains(role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you might call it

```
protected void saveUserRoles(Set<String> userRoles) {
    if (containsAny(userRoles, StaticValues.LUMEN_SELECT_USER_ROLE,
            StaticValues.EASY_SENSE_USER_ROLE, StaticValues.TLED_USER_ROLE, 
            StaticValues.IR_APP_USER_ROLE))) {
        preferences.setUserRoles(userRoles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Collections#disjoint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-) may help to make this more readable:

```
static final Set<String> ROLES_TO_SAVE = new HashSet<String>() {{
   add(StaticValues.LUMEN_SELECT_USER_ROLE);
   add(StaticValues.EASY_SENSE_USER_ROLE);
   // ...
}}    

protected void saveUserRoles(Set<String> userRoles) {
    if (userRoles != null && !Collections.disjoint(ROLES_TO_SAVE, userRoles))
        preferences.setUserRoles(userRoles);
}
```